# setInterval always showing initial value of deltaSec as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, undefined, setinterval

I'm having problem because this deltaSec variable is always being reset inside:

```
if(typeof deltaSec === "undefined"){...}
```

Even tried to parseInt the whole attribuition inside the condition to try to guarantee it as "number" type, as you can see.

And this condition verifying if deltaSec type is "number" was the first condition `(typeof deltaSec === "undefined")` "else" before I started to find the problem.

```
timeLineUpdater = setInterval(function (){
    var arrayTd = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
    if(typeof constructionTime === "undefined"){
        var constructionTime = document.getElementById("elementId").value;
    }
    if(typeof deltaSec == "number"){
        console.log(typeof deltaSec);
        if(deltaSec>0){
            deltaSec--;
        } else {
            deltaSec = deltaSec;
        }
    }
    if(typeof deltaSec === "undefined"){
        console.log(typeof deltaSec);
        var deltaSec = parseInt(60 - parseInt(constructionTime.split(":")[2]));
    }
    console.log(deltaSec);
    console.log(typeof deltaSec);
    if(deltaSec == 0){
        //do something
        deltaSec = 60;
    }
},1000);
```

As well as this was searching for solution:

```
if(deltaSec>0){
    deltaSec--;
} else {                  //this
    deltaSec = deltaSec;
}
```

Console actual results:

Infinite repetition of:

```
undefined
x //started value
number
```

Comment: How do you initialize `deltaSec` and where?

Comment: Looks like `deltaSec` is a global variable, or at least one not local to this function. Is it possible its value is being altered between calls to the timeout? (Because that's what it looks like - impossible to tell without more code though.)

Comment: It's being initialized right after it is identified as non initialized... line 15.

Comment: Where do you have the `var deltaSec` definition? Otherwise it will always be undefined.

Comment: Already said it's on line 15.
"var deltaSec = parseInt(60 - parseInt(constructionTime.split(":")[2]));"

@MihailMinkov Considering the insights you're suggesting, how could I assign this value only on the first run of this function?

Comment: As told before in this case you are creating the variable locally so all the other calls never affect the same variable. You'd have to create a var deltaSec outside of the `setInterval` and it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proper JS and expected behavior for your sample of code.

A declaration of variable starting with `var` anywhere within a lexical block (in this case, the `function() {}`) is hoisted to the start of the block. You can convince yourself of this with this (watch the console):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Before assignment");
  console.log(globalElement);
  var globalElement = "bar";
  console.log(globalElement);
}, 1000);
```

Your function is actually equivalent to the following:

```
timeLineUpdater = setInterval(function (){
    var deltaSec;
    var arrayTd = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
    if(typeof constructionTime === "undefined"){
        var constructionTime = document.getElementById("elementId").value;
    }
    if(typeof deltaSec == "number"){
        console.log(typeof deltaSec);
        if(deltaSec>0){
            deltaSec--;
        } else {
            deltaSec = deltaSec;
        }
    }
    if(typeof deltaSec === "undefined"){
        console.log(typeof deltaSec);
        deltaSec = parseInt(60 - parseInt(constructionTime.split(":")[2]));
    }
    console.log(deltaSec);
    console.log(typeof deltaSec);
    if(deltaSec == 0){
        //do something
        deltaSec = 60;
    }
},1000);
```

As a result, on the very first `if` statement, `deltaSec` is undefined (as it is specified as a local variable within that function somewhere further down, and the interpreter has already reserved this). As a result, the `undefined` if check is processed, which sets `deltaSec` to an integer.

Your next `console.log` (after the if statements) then prints it as an integer.

On the next loop, this behaviour starts anew, since the variable has not persisted elsewhere.

If you want to get rid of this behavior, drop the `var` in front of `deltaSec` assignments.

Comment: Please don't post related code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your answer/explanation becomes meaningless. Just place demo code into a "code snippet" right here in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the heads-up! The last time I answered questions properly on SO this feature did not exist. I will definitely make more use of it from here on.

Comment: "If you want to get rid of this behavior, drop the var in front of deltaSec assignments."

I really thought I NEEDED to use "var" on first ocurrence of a variable. Just using the variable without a single "var deltaSec" make things work!

Comment: And thanks for explaing how var is treated showing how it's interpreted with this equivalent code. Didn't know that as well.

Comment: @GilkanSolizaris You really do need to use a variable declaration, otherwise you are implicitly creating a Global variable, which should always be avoided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus incorrect. A single `var` declaration is enough to prevent a global variable from being accessible. His is in the second `if`. His intent is obviously to use the global variable (his code is an intention to delay something by 60 seconds, and the `setInterval` is there to check/enforce this delay). My explanation is centered purely around *why* this didn't work, and a step to remedy it.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld You misinterpreted what I said. I was talking about not having a formal declaration at all.

Comment: @GilkanSolizaris to elaborate further, the moment you declare a variable with `var`, you're effectively telling the interpreter to give you some space in the local scope for that variable. The moment that scope is over, the variable is gone. Within that scope, however, you are free to use/reuse that variable as often as you like.

I'm pretty sure we've all been bitten by this, by the way :-)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I assumed we're only seeing a snippet of the code here, and that the OP's snippet is part of a bigger file. After all, the code makes very little sense otherwise

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for explaining about using variables without "var" declaration handles them as global! But considering it's only a second timer, I'll not care about that for now, containing everything manually created as code inside the function only.

Comment: After all comments and answers I realized I could create a function to call the setIntervall and handle everything inside this outter scope, but it's only a second variation controller. Considering that, this is enough for my actual problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare `constructionTime` and `deltaSec` outside of the scope of the setInterval handler function. What happens with your code is that you declare your variables inside the scope of if clauses and they are not visible outside of that scope.  Btw, why `deltaSec = deltaSec;` in the else clause. That does nothing. I think your code should look like something like this, though I'm not sure what are you trying to do here.

```js
var deltaSec;
var constructionTime;
var timeLineUpdater = setInterval(function (){
    var arrayTd = document.getElementsByClassName("someclass");
    constructionTime = document.getElementById("elementId").value;
    deltaSec = 60 - parseInt(constructionTime.split(":")[2]);
    console.log(deltaSec);
    console.log(typeof deltaSec);
    if(deltaSec == 0){
        //do something
        deltaSec = 60;
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: I knew I could do things, but wanted to control everything from inside the function.

Comment: @GilkanSolizaris Have you tried taking the declaration out of the if clauses?